# Going back doesn't give me the right page

Tags: php, url-routing

I'm making a website with `PHP`. 
I have a list with activities and I have some filter options. 
The filter options are working well, but when I filter and go to the activity detail page and then go back. I end up on my home page, but the url is still alright.

This is the url when I use the filter option.

```
 index.php?action=page=activities&dayparts%5B%5D=2
```

Then I go to a detail page of one of the activities. Then I go back and I end up at the home page, while this is the url:

```
 index.php?action=page=activities&dayparts%5B%5D=2
```

Same url, but I redirect me back to the home page. When I don't use the filter option an if I go to a detail of an activity I won't go back to the home page.

This is how my `HTML` looks like:

```
<form id="form--filter" method="get" action="index.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="page" value="activities" />
```

And this is my `index.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$routes = array(
  'home' => array(
      'controller' => 'Home',
      'action' => 'index'
  ),
  'activities' => array(
      'controller' => 'Activities',
      'action' => 'activities'
  ),
  'activity-detail' => array(
      'controller' => 'Activities',
      'action' => 'detail'
  ),
  'yearly-detail' => array(
    'controller' => 'Activities',
    'action' => 'yearly'
  ),
  'locations' => array(
    'controller' => 'Locations',
    'action' => 'locations'
  ),
  'register' => array(
    'controller' => 'Register',
    'action' => 'register'
  ),
  'tickets' => array(
    'controller' => 'Tickets',
    'action' => 'tickets'
  ),
  'cart' => array(
    'controller' => 'Orders',
    'action' => 'cart'
  ),
  'checkout' => array(
    'controller' => 'Orders',
    'action' => 'checkout'
  )
);

if (empty($_GET['page'])) {
  $_GET['page'] = 'home';
}
if (empty($routes[$_GET['page']])) {
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit();
}

$route = $routes[$_GET['page']];
$controllerName = $route['controller'] . 'Controller';

require_once __DIR__ . '/controller/' . $controllerName . ".php";

$controllerObj = new $controllerName();
$controllerObj->route = $route;
$controllerObj->filter();
$controllerObj->render();
```

I somehow messed up somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: `action=page=activities` should not have more than 1 unencoded equal sign. Should it be `action=&page=activities`?

Comment: That is working yea, but how would I let the url automatically change to that? @waterloomatt

Comment: `... but when I filter and go to the activity detail page and then go back` can you please tell us more about this? How are you going back - redirect? Please share all your relevant code.